# How to use qcow2 disk image in Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, qemu

I have a large qcow2 formatted disk image, which I use as storage. Often I need to move data to and from this disk image. I mount the disk using the qemu-nbd tool as follows:

```
modprobe nbd max_part=63
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 /host/disk100G.img
mount /dev/nbd0p1 /home/rup/disk
```

But disk access fails every now and then in the midst of some I/O operation with an "Input/output error". At that point I have to manually unmount the disk and re-mount it so that I can run the program again:

```
qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
umount joborkhaki/
```

What could be the reason for this? Is there a better tool that I can use to maintain a qcow2 disk image?

Answer (score 1):

Use qemu-nbd with -n key solved the same problem for me.